# Azure Runbook Failed due to Storage Account Firewall

Tags: azure, azure-runbook

I have an Azure Runbook which runs every morning.

The Runbook executes 'Get-AzureStorageBlob' but since we enabled the firewall on the storage account, it now fails with error:

> Get-AzureStorageBlob : The remote server returned an error: (403)
>   Forbidden. HTTP Status Code: 403 - HTTP Error  Message: This request
>   is not authorized to perform this operation. At line:8 char:17
>   + ... ldBackups = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $BackupCtx -Container $Back ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureStorageBlob], StorageException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageBlobCommand

I have enabled 'Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account' on the storage account firewall, but it still fails.

Does anyone know how I can get this to run successfully?

Answer (score 0):

For now, the workaround is deploy a [Hybrid Runbook Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker), then add that public IP address to storage account's firewall, in this way, Azure storage will not block your runbook.

About the trusted Microsoft services:

[image]

The trusted Microsoft services not contain runbook.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: Hi @JasonYe , is this answer still the most suitable workaround?